# Parse download speed from wget output in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, wget

I have the following command

`sudo wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.pixelwolf.ch` which outputs

```
--2016-03-27 17:15:47-- http://speedtest.pixelwolf.ch/
Resolving speedtest.pixelwolf.ch (speedtest.pixelwolf.ch)... 178.63.18.88, 2a02:418:3102::6
Connecting to speedtest.pixelwolf.ch (speedtest.pixelwolf.ch) | 178.63.18.88|:80... connected.
HTTP Request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 85 [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null`

100%[======================>]85     --.-K/s in 0s

2016-03-27 17:15:47 (8.79 MB/s) - `dev/null` saved [85/85]
```

I'd like to be able to parse the `(8.79 MB/s)` from the last line and store this in a file (or any other way I can get this into a local PHP file easily), I tried to store the full output by changing my command to `--output-document=/dev/speedtest` however this just saved "Could not reach website" in the file and not the terminal output of the command.

Not quite sure where to start with this, so any help would be awesome.

Not sure if it helps, but my intention is for this stored value (`8.79`) in this instance to be read by a PHP file and handled there, every 30 seconds which I'll achieve by: `while true; do (run speed test and save speed variable to a file cmd); php handleSpeedTest.php; sleep 5; done` where handleSpeedTest.php will be able to read that stored value and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the URL to one that works. Redirected stderr onto stdout. Used grep --only-matching (-o) and a regex.

```
sudo wget -O /dev/null http://www.google.com 2>&1 | grep -o '\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)'
```

Comment: This just saves the contents of the google.com webpage into `dev/x` file, am I mis-understanding here?

Comment: @Jackhardcastle late reply, but whatever you write to`/dev/null` is discarded. It's being used since we're only interested in download speed and not actually keeping the file. Read more here: https://linuxhint.com/what_is_dev_null/